# How to get Teams call duration via Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

Is there a way to get user's Teams calls duration using Microsoft Graph API.
I can get total counts of calls and other reports using [Get user detail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/reportroot-getteamsuseractivityuserdetail?view=graph-rest-1.0).

But I didn't find reference on how to get details of each call.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it's not possible. You can, however, voice your interest in such a feature or [support similar ones](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/39502549-get-all-calls-of-a-user-with) in the [Microsoft Graph Feedback Forum](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests).

You can get call duration details from Teams Admin > [Analytics & reports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-analytics-and-reports/user-activity-report#view-the-report).

Answer (score 0):

you can find the duration of a call by using this request https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/communications/callRecords/getPstnCalls(fromDateTime=2021-06-01,toDateTime=2021-07-01) on ms graph or postman